# Cannot add bounty

Tags: support, bounties

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463854/hex-grid-map-with-pyqt4) question opened for 2 weeks and a half and I want to add bounty to it. I have read the process to add bounty but I cannot, as the add bounty button does not appear in the webpage. I tried with firefox, chrome and ie.

Any ideas what would be happening?

Comment: You need 75 rep to set bounties.  You only have 68 right now.

Comment: From the duplicate: *"You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount."*

Comment: Somehow I read needed rep was 50. Checking on the faq clearly states 75 as you say. Have no idea how I missed that! Thanks.

Comment: @victor you probably got confused with the "comment anywhere" privilege which indeed requires 50 rep. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gain the set bounty privilege at 75 reputation; you only have 68. You need another 7 reputation first.